# How to determine the number of domains of a specific country TLD?

Tags: dns, tld

As the title says,

lets say I want to get the number of .de domains:

Googling:

```
inurl:www.*.de
```

retrieves the correct results but a lot of them are from the same domain.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Considering domains are always being created, neglected, abandoned, parked, sold, sent through the intestinal tract of a ravenous bugblatter beast and worse you might want define the paramaters of your question a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the better search query would be: site:de

but even so, the result count of goolge is just a very very very blurry **page** estimate (a.k.a. completely wrong and not what you are looking for).

google is the wrong source for this.

but via google i found this
http://www.denic.de/hintergrund/geschichte-der-denic-eg.html

> August 2009   13 Millionen Domains
>   unterhalb von .de registriert –
>   darunter 463.000 IDNs.